# Debian Mips System Calls unistd.h Missing?

Tags: linux, assembly, debian, mips

I'm running Debian Squeeze mips architecture with qemu, and simply looking to figure out what the system calls are that I can put into $v0 to execute. I've found this [webpage](http://www.kneuro.net/cgi-bin/lxr/http/source/include/asm-mips/unistd.h?a=mips). Though this page does tell me the write command uses 4. I do the following:

I'm using [this image](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/main/installer-mips/current/images/malta/netboot/vmlinux-2.6.32-5-4kc-malta) to install Debian Squeeze.

Yes it is using mips as the system architecture:

```
uname -a
Linux debian 2.6.32-5-4kc-malta #1 Sat Feb 16 12:43:42 UTC 2013 mips GNU/Linux
```

--test.asm--

```
.global __start
.text
        __start:
        li $v0, 4
        li $a0, 1
        la $a1, out_string
        li $a2, 12
        syscall
.data
        out_string: .asciiz "Hello World\n"
```

Now I assemble using 'as' and link using 'ld'

```
as -march=mips32 -o test.o test.asm
ld -o test.out test.o
chmod +x test.out
./test.out
```

This unfortunately results in the error: `Illegal Instruction`.

I've compiled the following c program to determine what offset the write function uses and it's arguments to double check.

--write.c--

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     printf("Hello World\n");
     return 0;
}
```

Running `strace -i ./write.out` gives:

```
[2abbcbe0] write(1, "Hello World\n", 12Hello World)
```

The man page for write states the following:

```
#include <unistd.h>
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

I tried to use the write command to output "Hello World" and it does work just fine on it's own.

Here is a description of what the write function does and how I arrived at the way I've coded test.asm:

**fd or $a0** - The file descriptor which has been obtained from the call to open. It is an integer value. The values 0, 1, 2 can also be given, for standard input, standard output & standard error, respectively

**buff or $a1** - Points to a character array, which can be used to store content obtained from the file pointed to by fd.

**nbytes or $a2** - Specifies the number of bytes to be written from the character array into the file pointed to by fd.

Thus we arrive at the order:

```
#0x4 being what unistd.h for mips tells us the system call code is 4
$v0, 4
#Set first argument to the std output 1 for the file descriptor
$a0, 1
#Set the address for the string or buff
$a1, out_string
#Set nbytes or total bytes of the string
$a2, 12
```

This example works just fine in Mars and Spim though with one argument instead of 3:

--example.asm--

```
.data
    out_string: .asciiz "\nHello, World!\n"
.text
    main:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, out_string
    syscall
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Since I'm getting `Illegal Instruction` with test.asm this means I must be pointing to an invalid instruction. Though the system call code as observed before [here](http://www.kneuro.net/cgi-bin/lxr/http/source/include/asm-mips/unistd.h?a=mips). Is incorrect even though it's the unistd.h file for the mips architecture which we confirmed looking at the man page for write and the arguments it takes. So now I tryed strace thinking $v0 is pointing to the wrong instruction earlier and found the instruction pointer using `0x2abbcbe0`. Perhaps this will work? Let's try.

In strace the -i option prints the instruction pointer at time of the syscall.

So I edit the asm file

--test.asm--

```
.global __start
.text
        __start:
        li $v0, 0x2abbcbe0
        li $a0, 1
        la $a1, out_string
        li $a2, 12
        syscall
.data
        out_string: .asciiz "Hello World\n"
```

Run the assemble and link process again:

```
as -march=mips32 -o test.o test.asm
ld -o test.out test.o
chmod +x test.out
./test.out
```

This unfortunately results in the error: `Illegal Instruction` again.

I've also reversed the $a registers thinking I did this backwards, I ran strace multiple times and do confirm that the value in the instruction pointer doesn't change suggesting aslr is in-fact disabled. I've looked for the unistd.h file in /usr/include/ and it doesn't look anything like the one from the website presented in the beginning. The funny thing is this structure works perfect in spim and Mars both ones that simulate their print / write system calls using li $v0, 4. I understand that Mars and Spim use their own emulated system calls. Thought strace would find them for me but this seems to be not working out.

Where can I find the correct values for $v0? I feel like I've scraped Google to about where it's pointless now.

Perhaps I've messed up the asm file and it's syntax?

Let's try something more simple just running exit:

```
.global __start
.text
        __start:
        li $v0, 1
        li $a0, 0
        syscall
```

Assemble link and run

```
as -march=mips32 -o test.o test.asm
ld -o test.out test.o
chmod +x test.out
./test.out
Illegal Instruction
```

Also tried it without `-march=mips32`

```
as -o test.o test.asm
ld -o test.out test.o
chmod +x test.out
./test.out
Illegal Instruction
```

This should be the easiest thing to execute.

I'm at a loss here guys please help.

Comment: `$v0` should hold the syscall number, not some address. So 4 looks correct - certainly more so than 0x2abbcbe0. Your program never properly exits though, and that's not good. You should use the `exit` syscall (syscall number 1 according to the page you linked to).

Comment: When running qemu, which mips architecture are you using? And which port of Debian (debian-mips or debian-mipsel)

Comment: I'm using the image from http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/main/installer-mips/current/images/malta/netboot/

Comment: I guess the first observations is this. In your original `test.asm` that gives you an illegal instruction I notice you aren't actually exiting at the end and allowing your program to execute `Hello World\n` as code? I could see that causing an illegal instruction. After syscall to output the string, what happens if you exit back to the OS with `li $v0, 1` then `la $a0, 0` then `syscall`?

Comment: I've did the following to make a program to only exit based on the instructions you outlined: li $v0, 1 then li $a0, 0 and syscall. However this still just returns "Illegal Instruction". I totally agree with you the code for exit you have given here is correct however. It's still saying "Illegal Instruction" Seems very odd indeed does this have to do with the qemu emulation?

Comment: I'm not a mips developer so it was a hunch. If you exclude `-march=mips32` when running `as` what happens?

Comment: I run 'as -o test.o test.asm' then 'ld -o test.out test.o' then 'chmod +x test.out' then './test.out' which then gives me 'Illegal Instruction' This is of course using the simplest abstraction for exit that you've provided. And I totally agree with what you have there but it's still not working? Very strange indeed.

Comment: Why not run a.out under gdb to see what instruction is failing?

Comment: I just got exit to work by first making a static compile of this c file: `main(){exit(0);}` After this run `gcc -static -o exit exit.c`. Now I was able to access the `exit` function by `objdump -D exit | grep -A 24 "<_exit>:"`. I looked at the mips assembly and noticed jump if equal to zero or `beqz` pointing to several different places into the exit function. I noticed a few of them point to the next check while the last one does a jump to execute `li $v0, 4246` Low and behold I popped this into my assembly program as `li $v0, 4246 and li $a0, 0` I assemble as shown above. It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to use the Linux system calls then on the MIPS platform (Malta) you can find a list of the system calls [here](https://github.com/spotify/linux/blob/master/arch/mips/include/asm/unistd.h). On this architecture Linux maps its system calls starting at 4000. The ABI being used is MIPS o32. A snippet of the file is below. Please note that you can find a copy of the file on your system in  `/usr/include/asm/unistd.h`:

```
#define __NR_Linux          4000
#define __NR_exit           (__NR_Linux +   1)
#define __NR_write          (__NR_Linux +   4)
#define __NR_exit_group     (__NR_Linux + 246)
```

The following code should print `Hello World` and then exit:

```
    .text
    .globl  __start
__start:
    li $v0, 4004
    li $a0, 1
    la $a1, out_string
    li $a2, 12
    syscall
    li $v0, 4001
    la $a0, 1
    syscall

.data
    out_string: .asciiz "Hello World\n"
```

`__NR_exit_group` (4246) is defined in the Linux [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/2/exit_group) and differs from normal `exit` (4001) in one major way:

> This system call is equivalent to exit(2) except that it terminates not only the calling thread, but all threads in the calling process's thread group.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you for pointing out where to find the unistd.h file. This is very helpful indeed. Now I can proceed with learning mips easy now. Yes the 4246 is exit_group(0) I obtained it though a hacked look at the disassembly of the _exit function lol. Thanks a million!

Comment: Yeah, I added the 4246 in after since I noticed you had run across it yourself. Good luck!

Comment: I realize now I mis read the disassembly, and yeah 4001 is present there.